# OS X Masonry view animation without effect

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, masonry-ios-osx

#### [macOS | OS X] Masonry view animation without effect

- [✔️] I have looked at the [Documentation](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry/blob/master/README.md)
- [✔️] I have filled out this issue template.

#### Issue Info

- Platform: os x
- Platform Version: 10.12.6
- Masonry Version: 1.1.0

#### Issue Description

I'm using masonry autolayout in os x application project, I find out move animation in the view without effect. That is to say the view direct move to target location and no animation process.

My code is as follows:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext * _Nonnull context) {
    [context setDuration:0.5];
    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = YES;
    [_playlistView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.mas_right).with.offset(-kPlaylistBuoyBtnW-kPlaylistMainViewW);
    }];
} completionHandler:^{
    debugMethod();
}];
```

How to implement? It is best to use the sample code.

Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.

Comment: Try to call `[playlistView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]` after setting the constaint (after`make.left.euqal...`).

Answer (score 0):

First, declare an property in the view's interface.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MASConstraint *leftConstraint;
```

Secondly, use this property to do animation.

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext * _Nonnull context) {
    [context setDuration:kPlaylistPopAnimationTimes];
    context.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    _playlistView.leftConstraint.animator.offset(-kPlaylistBuoyBtnW-kPlaylistMainViewW);
} completionHandler:^{
    [_playlistView updateBuoyBtnState:state];
}];
```

Finally, other direction of animation is the same.